# How do you shut down an unresponsive program on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have a Windows 8.1 machine and I tried to install and launch Clip Studio Paint on it and the program is unresponsive.

The application window can't be moved, menus don't open, etc. Although it does seem to accept  focus / unfocus.

No idea what's going on.

I'd like to try shutting it down and restarting it.

On OS X I'd use the Activity Monitor app, or `ps aux | grep -i manga` and then `kill -9 [PID]`.

Is there a corresponding procedure on Windows?

Comment: GUI method use the task manager or the resource monitor, right click the item. in CMD or batch PV.exe is a good 3rd party progam to have. "Taskkill" is built in. (at least in win7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fred mentioned, the **Task Manager** is your friend. Besides the method he outlined, you can also press Alt+Ctrl+Del to get an overlay, then select 'Task Manager'; or you can press Ctrl+Shift+Esc to open it directly.

Just ending the task from the first panel that comes up (Processes pane) is not enough sometimes. In the event that it does not work, click the **More Details** option on the bottom left side of the **Task Manager** window, you will get a plethora of information about everything that is running.

After expanding the **Task Manager** to its full potential, find the offending application, right-click it and select **Go to details**. This will take you to the **Details** pane of the **Task Manager**. Once there, **right-click** the process that the previous step highlighted for you and select **End process tree**.

---

## EDIT

If you want to use the **Windows PowerShell** (hit start button/key, search for powershell), the command to kill a process by PID is `Stop-Process [PID]` without enclosing brackets. You can get the PID from the details pane in the **Task Manager**

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the details & info about Power Shell.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the task bar and then click on "Start Task Manager". From there click on Applications and then right click on your application and then click on End Process.